# Anatomical differences between herbivores and omnivores

Tags: physiology, zoology, food, anatomy, digestive-system

What are differences of herbivores vs omnivores? I do not mean dietary differences (obviously), but physical ones.

E.g., afaik herbivores have a much longer digestive tract than carnivores; then there is the difference in teeth, possession of carnivorous instincts or lack thereof, etc.

But where is the distinction between herbivores and omnivores? Is there a clear distinction at all, or is the border between the two groups somewhat fuzzy? Or are omnivores merely herbivores who are less picky?

#### EDIT

As pointed out in the comments, the last sentence seems to ask for dietary differences. It is not meant to; the only difference I am aware of is dietary, so it asks whether there are any anatomical distinctions, or the dietary is the only one. I.e. are they anatomically similar, and not distinguishable in the same way herbivores and carnivores are; hence are they herbivores that simply do not mind eating non-plant based food in a while?

I hope this serves to clarify.

#### EDIT 2

I realize that this question is quite broad, so while I am trying to get a good view of the bigger picture, partial answers will be more than welcome!

Comment: at first you're asking about anatomical differences, but your last paragraph seems more focused on the dietary behavior for which you said you *were* not asking about. If this is not the case, please clarify your question.

Comment: @theforestecologist I just did, I hope this clarifies!

Comment: This is a bit broad. Teeth, gastrointestinal differences (not alike in all herbivores), hooves/claws, eyes, etc, not to mention instincts... it's pretty broad.

Comment: @anongoodnurse I realize that it is. However, I lack the knowledge to narrow it down. Also, I am basically interested in the big picture, i.e. pretty much anything having an impact on how they feed.

Comment: @foaly Instead of making additional sections like **EDIT1** or **EDIT2** while retaining the original content, please **actually edit** the question so that it becomes short and precise.

Comment: @WYSIWYG For exactly that purpose I did not. The question is still correct and as precise as I can make it without wordy explanations. If anyone feels uncertain about it though, there is a clarification below in the edits. ;)